# MySQL Trigger - Update relation table with extra values

Tags: mysql, triggers, relational-database

[image: Relation Model]

What I'm trying to achieve is, I want to automate the values of the table between the **users** and **folders** table. Since it's a many-to-many relationship I created the **user_folders** table. Currently the server (nodejs) gets the request with *userid*, *clientfolderid* and some an array of bookmarks (which are not important now). It checks if the user already has this folder, by selecting from the **user_folders** table and if it's not existing it inserts a new row into the **folder** table. Then it has to send another statement to insert into the **user_folders** table.

So I have to "manually" keep the **users_folder** table updated.I guess this is a common problem and wanted to know if there is a pattern or a proven solution? The odd thing is that MySQL automatically handles the deletion of rows with an AFTER DELETE trigger but there is no (at least that I know of) automation with an AFTER INSERT trigger.

As I already said an AFTER INSERT trigger could possibly solve it, but I think it's not possible to pass some extra parameters to the AFTER INSERT trigger. This would be the user_id and the folder_client_id in my case.

I was thinking of a solution that I could create another table called **tmp_folder** which would look like:

```
tmp_folder
-- id
-- title
-- changed
-- user_id
-- folder_client_id
```

Then create an AFTER INSERT trigger on this table which inserts into folders and user_folders and then removes the row from **tmp_folder** again. Would this be the right way or is there a better one?

I would basically do the same with the bookmarks and user_bookmarks table. The best thing would be if it's even possible to insert a folder then the owner into the **user_folders** table with user_id and folder_client_id and then multiple other users into **user_folders** with the user_id and an default folder_client_id of -1 or something which will be updated later.

Meanwhile thanks for reading and I hope you can help me :)

PS: Is there a name for the table between 2 other tables in an m-2-m relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an easy way to do this via triggers, but a stored procedure may suit you:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE 
add_user_folder(
    IN  u_user_id BIGINT UNSIGNED,
    IN  u_folder_client_id BIGINT UNSIGNED,
    IN  v_title    VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE u_found INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT
        1 INTO u_found
    FROM
        user_folders
    WHERE
        user_id = u_user_id AND
        folder_client_id = u_folder_client_id;

    IF IFNULL(u_found, 0) = 0 THEN
        START TRANSACTION;

        INSERT INTO
        folders
        SET
        title = v_title,
        changed = UNIX_TIMESTAMP();

        INSERT INTO
        user_folders
        SET
        user_id = u_user_id,
        folder_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(),
        folder_client_id = u_folder_client_id;

        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END;
//
```